# Error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: package-management, upgrade, libraries

I've upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10. Unfortunately when I try to start xen with these commands :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/xencommons start
sudo /etc/init.d/xendomains start
sudo /etc/init.d/xen-watchdog start
sudo /etc/init.d/xendriverdomain start
```

I get this error :

```
Starting /usr/local/sbin/oxenstored...Setting domain 0 name, domid and JSON config...
Done setting up Dom0
Starting xenconsoled...
Starting QEMU as disk backend for dom0
/usr/local/lib/xen/bin/qemu-system-i386: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
* [done]
Starting xen-watchdog (via systemctl): xen-watchdog.service.
```

It didn't happen with Ubuntu 20.04, so 20.10 removed some "obsolete" package. I tried to reinstall some packages related to nettle component, but the error didn't go away. Somone wants to help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libnettle.so.7) by

```
sudo apt-get install libnettle7:i386
```

or manually by

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nettle/libnettle7_3.5.1+really3.5.1-2_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libnettle7_3.5.1+really3.5.1-2_i386.deb
```

Comment: done. the error is still there,intact.

Comment: maybe this is the right file ? ---> ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/nettle/libnettle7_3.5.1+really3.5.1-2_amd64.deb

Comment: no. it isn't : Estrazione di libnettle7:amd64 (3.5.1+really3.5.1-2)...
dpkg: errore nell'elaborare l'archivio /etc/xen/libnettle7_3.5.1+really3.5.1-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 tentata sovrascrittura di "/usr/share/doc/libnettle7/changelog.Debian.gz" (condiviso), diverso da altre istanze del pacchetto libnettle7:amd64
dpkg-deb: errore: il sottoprocesso paste è stato terminato dal segnale (Pipe interrotta)